# Facebook iframe popup

Tags: javascript, facebook

I can't get this working. I'm trying to show something [like this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) (see the image image from the "send to many" section). I'm getting the message "An error occurred. Please try again later."

The code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.ui({title: 'title', display: 'iframe', 
        method: 'apprequests', message: 'check this out.'
    });
}
```

Edit1:
The popup window shows, but inside it there's no list of friends but the above message.

Edit2:
And of course my app requests permissions for user's friends list on first launch.

Comment: Did you tried removing `display: 'iframe'`? I think you don't need it.

Comment: Well I want the popup to display in iframe, so I actually need it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and I get the dialog load with all the users.

I would suggest checking your application id to make sure it is correct.

Below is the code I am using:

```
            //run the script code to get the facebook javascript sdk
            (function(){
                var e = document.createElement('script'); 
                e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());

            //run when sychronisation of facebook javascript sdk is finished
            window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
                //initialise the application 
                FB.init({appId: '<?=APPLICATION_ID?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});
                FB.ui({title: 'title', display: 'iframe', method: 'apprequests', message: 'check this out.'
                    }); 
            };
```

Comment: That was probably some facebook js issue (which happens too often) - right now I don't remember what did I do to take care of this problem, but I'm sure my app id was correct. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the function getLoginStatus, to be sure that the `FB.init` function has finished to load.

I just solved same problem this way:

*note that I'm using jQuery*

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            FB.init({ appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                FB.ui({ title: 'Invite friends', display: 'iframe', method: 'apprequests', message: 'check this out.' });
            });
        });
    </script>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
```